# Python Qt: Interactive Re-Sizable QGraphicsItem, mouse hover area not resizing

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, pyside, qgraphicsitem

I am trying to build a python class around `QGraphicsRectItem` (PySide or PyQt4) that provides mouse interaction through hover-overs, is movable, and re-sizable. I have pretty much everything working except:

**For some reason, it seems as if the mouse hover area is not changing when the item is re-sized or moved. I need help solving this issue.**

Maybe the problem is caused by inverting the y axis on the `QGraphicsView`:

```
QGraphicsView.scale(1,-1)
```

---

### QGraphicsRectItem class:

```
class BoxResizable(QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, rect, parent = None, scene = None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, rect, parent, scene)
        
        self.setZValue(1000)
        self._rect = rect
        self._scene = scene
        self.mouseOver = False
        self.resizeHandleSize = 4.0
        
        self.mousePressPos = None
        self.mouseMovePos = None
        self.mouseIsPressed = False
        
        self.setFlags(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable|QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable)
        self.setAcceptsHoverEvents(True)
             
        self.updateResizeHandles()
    
    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        self.updateResizeHandles()
        self.mouseOver = True
        self.prepareGeometryChange()
    
    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.mouseOver = False
        self.prepareGeometryChange()

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, event):

        if self.topLeft.contains(event.scenePos()) or self.bottomRight.contains(event.scenePos()):
            self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
        elif self.topRight.contains(event.scenePos()) or self.bottomLeft.contains(event.scenePos()):
            self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.SizeBDiagCursor)
        else:
            self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.SizeAllCursor)
        
        QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """
        Capture mouse press events and find where the mosue was pressed on the object
        """
        self.mousePressPos = event.scenePos()
        self.mouseIsPressed = True
        self.rectPress = copy.deepcopy(self._rect)
        
        # Top left corner
        if self.topLeft.contains(event.scenePos()):
            self.mousePressArea = 'topleft'
        # top right corner            
        elif self.topRight.contains(event.scenePos()):
            self.mousePressArea = 'topright'
        #  bottom left corner            
        elif self.bottomLeft.contains(event.scenePos()):
            self.mousePressArea = 'bottomleft'
        # bottom right corner            
        elif self.bottomRight.contains(event.scenePos()):
            self.mousePressArea = 'bottomright'
        # entire rectangle
        else:
            self.mousePressArea = None
            
        QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.mousePressEvent(self, event)
    
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        """
        Capture nmouse press events.
        """
        self.mouseIsPressed = False

        self.updateResizeHandles()
        self.prepareGeometryChange()
        
        QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        """
        Handle mouse move events.
        """
        self.mouseMovePos = event.scenePos()
        
        if self.mouseIsPressed:
            # Move top left corner
            if self.mousePressArea=='topleft':
                self._rect.setTopLeft(self.rectPress.topLeft()-(self.mousePressPos-self.mouseMovePos))
            # Move top right corner            
            elif  self.mousePressArea=='topright':
                self._rect.setTopRight(self.rectPress.topRight()-(self.mousePressPos-self.mouseMovePos))
            # Move bottom left corner            
            elif  self.mousePressArea=='bottomleft':
                self._rect.setBottomLeft(self.rectPress.bottomLeft()-(self.mousePressPos-self.mouseMovePos))
            # Move bottom right corner            
            elif  self.mousePressArea=='bottomright':
                self._rect.setBottomRight(self.rectPress.bottomRight()-(self.mousePressPos-self.mouseMovePos))
            # Move entire rectangle, don't resize
            else:
                self._rect.moveCenter(self.rectPress.center()-(self.mousePressPos-self.mouseMovePos))
            
            self.updateResizeHandles()
            self.prepareGeometryChange()
            
        QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.mousePressEvent(self, event)
        
    def boundingRect(self):
        """
        Return bounding rectangle
        """
        return self._boundingRect
        
    def updateResizeHandles(self):
        """
        Update bounding rectangle and resize handles
        """
        self.offset = self.resizeHandleSize*(self._scene.graphicsView.mapToScene(1,0)-self._scene.graphicsView.mapToScene(0,1)).x()        
    
        self._boundingRect = self._rect.adjusted(-self.offset, self.offset, self.offset, -self.offset)

        # Note: this draws correctly on a view with an inverted y axes. i.e. QGraphicsView.scale(1,-1)
        self.topLeft = QtCore.QRectF(self._boundingRect.topLeft().x(), self._boundingRect.topLeft().y() - 2*self.offset,
                                     2*self.offset, 2*self.offset)
        self.topRight = QtCore.QRectF(self._boundingRect.topRight().x() - 2*self.offset, self._boundingRect.topRight().y() - 2*self.offset,
                                     2*self.offset, 2*self.offset)
        self.bottomLeft = QtCore.QRectF(self._boundingRect.bottomLeft().x(), self._boundingRect.bottomLeft().y(),
                                     2*self.offset, 2*self.offset)
        self.bottomRight = QtCore.QRectF(self._boundingRect.bottomRight().x() - 2*self.offset, self._boundingRect.bottomRight().y(),
                                     2*self.offset, 2*self.offset)
                                     
    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        """
        Paint Widget
        """
        
        # show boundingRect for debug purposes
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 0, QtCore.Qt.DashLine))
        painter.drawRect(self._boundingRect)
        
        # Paint rectangle
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 0, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawRect(self._rect)
        
        # If mouse is over, draw handles
        if self.mouseOver:
            # if rect selected, fill in handles
            if self.isSelected():
                painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0,0,0)))
            painter.drawRect(self.topLeft)
            painter.drawRect(self.topRight)
            painter.drawRect(self.bottomLeft)
            painter.drawRect(self.bottomRight)
```

---

### Rest of code for functioning example:

```
class graphicsScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsScene.__init__(self, parent)
    def setGraphicsView(self, view):
        self.graphicsView = view

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle('GTK')
mainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()

scene = graphicsScene()
scene.setSceneRect(-100,-100, 200, 200)

# Set up view properties
view = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
view.setScene(scene)
view.scale(1,-1)
view.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
view.setViewportUpdateMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.BoundingRectViewportUpdate)

view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy ( QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff )
view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy ( QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff )
view.setUpdatesEnabled(True)
view.setMouseTracking(True)

view.setCacheMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.CacheBackground)

view.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)

scene.setGraphicsView(view)

# Add box
BoxResizable(QtCore.QRectF(-50, 50, 100.0, -100.0), parent = None, scene = scene)

mainWindow.setCentralWidget(view)
mainWindow.show()

app.exec_()

app.deleteLater()
sys.exit()
```

---

Adding the above class to a `QGraphicsScene` and subsequent inverted y axis `QGraphicsView` will produce something like this:

[image]

Any help or suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why does the graphicsItem appear at the center of the window ? Can you explain a little bit about the coordinates here? `scene.setSceneRect(-100,-100, 200, 200)` and `BoxResizable(QtCore.QRectF(-50, 50, 100.0, -100.0), parent = None, scene = scene)`  Why the x y values can be negative, and what does a negative height mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found part of the problem: If I over-ride the shape function (add this function to the class) with:

```
    def shape(self):
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRect(self.boundingRect())
        return path
```

The hover area changes size and position with the box sometimes. Acoording to the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#shape) for `QGraphicsItem.shape()`:

> The default implementation calls boundingRect() to return a simple
>   rectangular shape...

Is this a bug in PyQt4?

Second problem: I think that the boundingRect and the shape rectangle need to have positive widths and heights? This is easily done by adding:

```
self._rect = self._rect.normalized()
```

to the `mouseReleaseEvent` function.

Comment: I am having problem about resize a QGraphicsItem, I wanted to study your code, but it generates some mistakes, you could share the complete code here, github or something?